# Capture a sceenshot and save it in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

Can i have a macro that will create  a screen shot of my selected window  and save it in a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stolen shamelessly (but tested) from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-customize/export-a-range-of-cells-from-excel-as-jpg/756b76a8-8175-40f2-9855-ff6d55c051e7):

```
Sub test()
    Dim cht As Chart
    With Range("A1:E10")
    .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, .Width, _
    .Height).Chart
    End With
    cht.Paste
    cht.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill "testChart.jpg"
    On Error GoTo 0
    cht.Export "testChart.jpg", "jpg"
    cht.Parent.Delete
End Sub
```

I assume you mean selected `Range`, not window, else a keystroke will do. We need to replace `Range("A1:E10")` with `Selection`, and wrap it in an error check, because [`Selection`s are a little risky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)