# take screen shot of active window after every 5 min and save it in a file

Tags: c#

already searched but did not get help from anywhere!
[Capture a sceenshot and save it in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404830/capture-a-sceenshot-and-save-it-in-a-folder)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture screenshot of active window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

Comment: take screen shot is done...but problem is that i want to save image after every 5 min...using this method
  var image = ScreenCapture.CaptureActiveWindow();
                image.Save(@"D:\documents\FYP\snippetsource.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);.........but it replaces old image i want to save all images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is in how to run a task every 5 minutes. Use Timers:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds);

timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
timer.Start();

private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // call the function that takes the screenshot
}
```

Comment: timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;......... it does not call to Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)..........I'm calling it like this: var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds);
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;

Comment: @muneeb sorry you need to use `timer.Start();`

Comment: Thanks its done.......var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
            aTimer.Interval = 1000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;......... this code solved my problem.....really thanks to you also :)

Comment: @muneeb http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

use this function to capture screen:

```
private static Image CaptureScreen()
    {
        Rectangle screenSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        var target = new Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height));
        }
        return target;
    }
```

Saving to file:

```
var currentImage = CaptureScreen();
currentImage.Save(Path.Combine("Your directory path", "Your file name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a new file name each time you save the image, meaning, instead of:

```
image.Save(@"D:\documents\FYP\snippetsource.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Do something like:

```
image.Save(string.Format(@"D:\documents\FYP\snippetsource_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

You can change `Guid.NewCuid()` with whatever unique string that makes more sense to your application.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks its helpful.......var currentImage = ScreenCapture.CaptureScreen();
            //currentImage.Save(Path.Combine(@"D:\documents\FYP", "abc.jpg"));
            currentImage.Save(string.Format(@"dll\snippetsource_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()), ImageFormat.Jpeg);............when I'm calling Time_Elapsed it does not work............I'm calling it like this:  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds);

            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed; }

Comment: Try storing the created timer instance in a class level private memeber instead of a local method variable.